# Is it possible to render a parent component in child component

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

1.Created a component called .

2.Created a child component called   and included in .

3.Tried to include  in  ends in infinite loop.

[DEMO - Circular Dependency](https://stackblitz.com/edit/circularref?embed=1&file=app/parent/child/child.component.html)

Comment: That's correct error. If you want to render once you should stop circular execution for example by passing some parameter

Comment: Does creating a Dynamic component helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is , but you need to be very careful and also sure about what are you doing :

Here I have created a demo on 'Circular Dependency' but with specific data , so it won't go the infinite loop and breaks at some level

Have a look

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-circularref)**